# Designing a simple fan + resistor system for heating air

Tags: resistors, heat, fan

I have a research application that requires a steady supply of heated air. My current plan is to 3D-print a small tank (6" x 6" x 4") to which a muffin fan will be fastened. The fan will blow air across a 20W resistor into the tank to heat the air. The heated air will continuously leave the tank through an exit port and travel to the application for which the air is needed. The exiting air will need to be maintained at 37C +/- 1C.

Here is a schematic of the device:

[image]

To get the correct temperature, I will adjust the **fan speed** (variable CFM). This is my attempt at calculating the necessary fan speed:

```
Ambient air temp: T1 = 25C

Final air temp: T2 = 37C

Resistor power: P = 20 W

Heat capacity of air: c = 1 J/gK

Density of air: d = 1.15 g/L

air flow rate: f = P/[(c)(d)(T2-T1)] = 20/[(1)(1.15)(37-25)] 

= 1.45 L/s = 3.1 CFM
```

This is not my area of expertise so I was wondering if I could get some feedback on my proposed method. Do the calculations seem sound? Do you foresee any issues with this system as a whole?

Comment: It looks plausible, though as Michael says, vary the power to the resistor using PWM. You might want to put some baffles (like muslin or netting) in the box to mix it thoroughly. Also, be sure your fan can deliver 3.1 CFM **at the head you anticipate**. You can back calculate from the pressure drop using elementary fluid dynamics. Use a fast responding temperature sensor at the exit port- you already have a control dead time issue because of mass transfer and adding unnecessary lag is adding insult to injury.

Comment: If this is just a one pf R&D/prototype build I would use a large heatsink in the baffle/chamber with a to-220 or to-247 mounted to it to regulated outlet temperature

Comment: 3d printing a box like that? probably cheaper to buy or fabricate one.  or re-purpose a food storage container (cookie tin, or lunch-box).  a 20W resistor is about 2" long.  and the leads will get hot.

Comment: It seems likely that a good deal of the energy output will end up radiantly heating the hub of the fan, until it seizes, stops blowing, and possibly catches fire.

Comment: @Jasen, I'd cut a hole in a *metal* box to do this.  That way when the fan fails or somethign falls in and blocks it, th box won't melt before your thermal cutout opens (OP: where is that in the schematic, by the way?)

Comment: How large is the exit hole? Is the fan able to build up enough pressure to force all that air through the hole? The tube in your schematic looks pretty small, intuitively I doubt a computer case fan (like the one pictured) is able to build up enough pressure.

Comment: To add: A quick back-of-the envelope calculation shows that you’d need 112 Pa of pressure for a 1 m long tube with 10 mm diameter to achieve 1.45 L/s. A fast industrial fan would be able to provide that, e.g.: http://www.ebmpapst.com/en/products/compact-fans/axial-compact-fans/axial_compact_fans_detail.php?pID=231969 For a 5 mm diameter tube you’d need 1800 Pa.

Edit: However the airflow of the fan to achieve a high enough pressure is way too great. It would all escape back through the fan.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All of the energy output of the resistor will end up in the exit airflow, regardless of fan speed (to first order).

Your plan is to vary the output temperature by controlling the air flow rate, that is, the mass of air the energy is diluted in. Most people (myself included) would have adopted a fixed fan speed, and varied the amount of power being delivered by the resistor.

While basically equivalent, the two schemes have different features, none of which make either approach a no-brainer.

- The variable airflow method will have a slightly lower latency from control input to temperature output, especially if a big fat resistor is used for the heater, many small resistors in parallel would be faster in that case. Latency is important for stability with feedback control, though I would expect most of the latency will come from the physical transport, then heating the tank, tube, and components in line to the monitored exit.
- Set against that, the variable fan speed method will have variable latency, due to changing the transit time for the tube. If you are servoing the temperature at the output, this could cause you loop tuning and stability problems, unless you tune for the lowest fan speed.
- The variable fan speed will act as an audible monitor of what the loop is doing. That may be useful, or irritating, or inaudible above the lab.
- The fluid dynamics around the experiment may well be sensitive to fan speed. I might be concerned that having got layout right at one speed, things could change at another.
- Power control uses less energy. Set the airflow to the minimum required, then the resistor output is automatically controlled to the minimum output. Though at 20w and presumably mains powered, this is a small consideration.
- Apparent overshoot is built-in to the flow regulated system. Consider a flow regulated shower. Let's say the water is too hot. I turn the flow up, and until the cooler water reaches the shower head, I feel even hotter as the faster flow delivers heat to my skin faster, but doesn't cool down until after the transit latency. Depending on whether heat is being lost continuously from your experiment, this effect may or may be relevant.

I must confess I thought I'd find more reasons in support of the (for most people) 'normal' way of power control.

If the plastic tube on the barb is intended to be the air supply to your experiment, then it looks a very poor match of fan and fan load resistance. That's a high-flow low-head fan, and it will be essentially stalled into that thin long tube.

Answer (score 4):

Since it is the fan that will deliver the air via the exit port tube I would suggest that you will not want to vary the fan speed as that will cause a variation in the air flow out of the exit port.

Instead you should setup a PWM driver to vary the duty cycle of the power to the resistor. This PWM duty cycle would be controlled through a feedback system that monitors the air temperature at the exit port of the box. This scheme allows the fan speed to be kept constant and permits a consistent air flow in the exit tube.

One of the easiest methods of monitoring the air temperature at the exit port is to place a 1N4148 diode onto the air stream that is biased with a constant 1mA of current. Then measure the forward voltage drop across the diode with an opamp gain circuit and an A/D converter.

Comment: The volumetric flow rate isn't actually important to me, as long as it's the correct temperature. We plan to modulate fan speed via feedback from a downstream temperature probe to an arduino. Maybe a variable resistor would simplify the picture though...

Comment: drive the a fixed resistor via a transistor controlled by a PWM signal (to generate PWM from arduino use `analogwrite()`

Comment: “One of the easiest methods of monitoring the air temperature at the exit port is to place a 1N4148 diode onto the air stream that is biased with a constant 1mA of current.” or use one of the reliable, calibrated sensors with I2C interface you can get for <2€.

Comment: @Michael - I tend to not agree. The integrated circuit sensors that would have an I2C interface are generally much more difficult to get packaged into a real working solution. An I2C sensor typically requires at least four wires and maybe even a circuit board at the sensor point. Note that there are several monitor chips available that you can put off on a circuit board and wire up to external Si diodes or discrete Si transistor BE junctions such as the ADT7476.

Comment: @MichaelKaras: Here is a breakout board of a MCP9808 for 4.95$ which would easily fit in the box: https://www.adafruit.com/product/1782 They also offer an Arduino library which would be advantageous since OP is using an Arduino.

Another idea: Placing said Arduino inside the box and using its internal temperature sensor. However, I guess the accuracy wouldn’t be great.

Comment: Adding additional heat generators to the system seems like it complicates things way more than necessary if that be a temp sensor chip, a break out board or even an MCU board. So I still disagree with you.

Comment: On of the easiest ways of measuring the temperature, especially with a narrow range like the OP asks for, is with a thermistor, much larger and more measurement-friendly output than a silicon diode.